# Change side of SwiftUI .toolbar

Tags: ios, swift

How do you adjust the vertical height of the .toolbar with SwiftUI? As seen in the image below, the toolbar is way too large (all I need it to do is just to fit those three items):

[image: Too large toolbar]

```
            NavigationView {
            VStack{
                MapView()
                }.toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                        HStack(spacing: 20) {
                            Text("Toolbar")
                            Divider()
                            Button(action: {}) {Image(systemName: "plus.circle")}
                            Divider()
                            Button(action: {}) {Image(systemName:"arrowshape.turn.up.left.circle") 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                
           }
```

Comment: Fit those three items where exactly? Also,  what do you mean when you said, "toolbar is way too large?" You mean toolbar (all 3 items) or that `Text("Toolbar")`?

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is to remove the amount of vertical whitespace (such that the MapView would be higher up). (I meant the toolbar itself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct ContentView: View {
        var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                VStack{
                    MapView()
                }.toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    HStack(spacing: 20) {
                        Text("Toolbar")
                        Divider()
                    Button(action: {}) {Image(systemName: "plus.circle")}
                        Divider()
                    Button(action: {}) {Image(systemName:"arrowshape.turn.up.left.circle")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}
```

**Result:**
[image]